# Flutter Layout/Sizing/Render Issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to dynamically render a list of DailyWeatherForecast, a Flutter StatelessWidget. The DailyWeatherForecast widget has some variables such as `final String month` and `final double low`, which intend to act as a single summarized forecast for a day as a narrow card. It has a constructor, and it works if I pass in hard-coded values to it from my main.dart. It looks and works great.

Information is pulled from an API though. So, I can't have this information hard-coded. See the code below for my approach:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo/classes/daily_weather_forecast.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

// `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var lat = "35";
  var lon = "139";
  var exclude = "minutely,hourly";
  var appid = "<HIDDEN>";
  var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall";
  Map? weatherData;
  //List<Map>? dailyWeather;
  Iterable<int>? dailyWeather;
  var now = DateTime.now();
  List months = [
    'Jan',
    'Feb',
    'Mar',
    'Apr',
    'May',
    'Jun',
    'Jul',
    'Aug',
    'Sep',
    'Oct',
    'Nov',
    'Dec'
  ];

  void callApis() {
    debugPrint('test???');

    var endpoint = url +
        "?lat=" +
        lat +
        "&lon=" +
        lon +
        "&exclude=" +
        exclude +
        "&appid=" +
        appid;

    debugPrint(endpoint);

    http.get(endpoint, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}).then((result) {
      setState(() {
        debugPrint(result.headers.toString());
        weatherData = json.decode(result.body);
        if (weatherData != null) {
          //dailyWeather = weatherData!['daily'];
          dailyWeather =
              Iterable<int>.generate(weatherData!['daily'].length).toList();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    debugPrint('test???');
    //fetchWeatherData();
    callApis();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          actions: const <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.cloud_circle,
              size: 36,
              //color: Colors.black54,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(7, 101, 162, 1),
            ),
            //spacing to the right
            SizedBox(width: 12)
          ],
          title: Text(
              weatherData != null
                  ? weatherData!["timezone"]
                      .toString() //weatherData![0]['name'].toString()
                  : "Weather App",
              style: const TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(7, 101, 162, 1))),
        ),
        /* NOTE: ListView is RecycleView equivalent in Flutter */
        body: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            FractionallySizedBox(
              widthFactor: 0.8,
              child: Column(
                children: dailyWeather?.map(
                      (index) {
                        int i = index.round();
                        Map dayData = weatherData?["daily"][i];
                        debugPrint("DAY DATA: " + dayData.toString());
                        if (dayData["temp"] == null) {
                          return const Text("nil");
                        }
                        if (dayData["weather"] == null ||
                            dayData["weather"] == []) {
                          return const Text("nil");
                        }

                        return Row(
                          children: [
                            // spacer
                            Container(
                              height: 24,
                            ),
                            DailyWeatherForecast(
                                month: months[now.month - 1].toString(),
                                day: (now.day + i).round(),
                                high: dayData["temp"]["max"],
                                low: dayData["temp"]["min"],
                                probability: dayData["rain"],
                                excerpt: dayData["weather"][0]["main"],
                                description: dayData["weather"][0]
                                    ["description"]),
                            // spacer
                            Container(
                              height: 64,
                            )
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    ).toList() ??
                    [
                      Image.network(
                          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Youtube_loading_symbol_1_(wobbly).gif")
                    ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below you can see the daily_weather_forecast.dart file, and the errors (in that order):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DailyWeatherForecast extends StatelessWidget {
  /* Numeric day of the month */
  final String month;
  final int day;
  final double high;
  final double low;
  final double probability;
  /* Shorter description; "Sunny and Warm" */
  final String excerpt;
  /* Longer description; "Cloudless and generally warm, with a high of 75F and a low of 57F. Some high clouds late in the day." */
  final String description;

  /* constructors */
  const DailyWeatherForecast(
      {Key? key,
      required this.month,
      required this.day,
      required this.high,
      required this.low,
      required this.probability,
      required this.excerpt,
      required this.description})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(description));
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        },
        child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(7, 101, 162, 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                const SizedBox(width: 20, height: 64),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(month,
                        style:
                            const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12)),
                    Text(day.toString(),
                        style:
                            const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18))
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 20),
                Text(low.toString() + "F",
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                const Spacer(),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(excerpt,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                    Text(probability.toString() + "%  precipation",
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white70)),
                  ],
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Text(high.toString() + "F",
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                const SizedBox(width: 20),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

Here's the FULL terminal output (removing the DAY DATA logs, to stay under character limits):

```
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/flutter (13021): test???
I/flutter (13021): test???
I/flutter (13021): ENDPOINT: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=44.5630283&lon=-123.3185558&exclude=minutely,hourly&units=imperial&appid=1402ba071d730e537b18335ee1dcbdb2
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
   149ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).   
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

Running with unsound null safety
For more information see
https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

An Observatory debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 isavailable at: http://127.0.0.1:57917/zOC4HZuw9FM=/


══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height
constraints are unbounded.
When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height  
constraint, for example if it is
in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children   
along the vertical axis. Setting a
flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is toexpand to fill the remaining
space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to      
shrink-wrap its child, the child
cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using
FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the 
flexible children to size
themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would     
otherwise be forced to take, and
then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather   
than expanding to fit the maximum
constraints provided by the parent.
If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider    
using debugDumpRenderTree():
  https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
  http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html 
The affected RenderFlex is:
  RenderFlex#7ff70 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT    
  NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE(creator: Column ← Column ←
  FractionallySizedBox ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ←       
  NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ←
  AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree ← SliverList ← MediaQuery ←     
  SliverPadding ← ⋯, parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null;  fit=null (can use size), constraints:
  BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=314.2, 0.0<=h<=Infinity), size: MISSING,   
  direction: vertical, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: max, 
  crossAxisAlignment: center, verticalDirection: down)
The creator information is set to:
  Column ← Column ← FractionallySizedBox ← RepaintBoundary ←        
  IndexedSemantics ←
  NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ←
  AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree ←
  SliverList ← MediaQuery ← SliverPadding ← ⋯
See also: https://flutter.dev/layout/
If none of the above helps enough to fix this problem, please don't 
hesitate to file a bug:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md   

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Column
  Column:file:///C:/Users/Lucas%20Pichette/Desktop/School/W22/CS492_  Mobile_Software_Dev/assignment2-api/todo/lib/main.dart:162:29     

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      RenderFlex.performLayout.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:926:9)
#1      RenderFlex.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:929:6)
#2      RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#3      ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild
(package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#4      RenderFlex._computeSizes
(package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
#5      RenderFlex.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#6      RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#7      RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:1165:14)
#8      RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#9      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#10     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#11     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#12     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#13     RenderSliverList.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:213:28)
#14     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#15     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:12)
#16     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:371:11)
#17     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#18     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence
(package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:510:13)
#19     RenderViewport._attemptLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1580:12)
#20     RenderViewport.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1489:20)
#21     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#22     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#23     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#25     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#26     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#27     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#29     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#31     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#32     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#33     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#34     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#35     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#36     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#37     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#38     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#40     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#41     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#42     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1005:7)
#43     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#44     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:403:14)
#45     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#46     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#47     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#48     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#49     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1376:11)
#50     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#51     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#52     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#53     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#54     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#55     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#56     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#57     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#58     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#59     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#60     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#61     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#62     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#63     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#64     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#65     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#66     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#68     RenderOffstage.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3428:13)
#69     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#70     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#71     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#72     _RenderTheatre.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:751:15)
#73     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#74     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#75     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#76     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#77     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#78     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#79     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#80     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#81     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#82     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#83     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#84     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#85     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#86     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#87     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#88     RenderView.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:165:14)
#89     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1707:7)
#90     PipelineOwner.flushLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:879:18)
#91     RendererBinding.drawFrame
(package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:497:19)
#92     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
(package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#93     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
(package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#94     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1145:15)
#95     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#96     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure>    
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:863:7)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer,     
dart:async, and dart:async-patch)

The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception   
was fired: RenderFlex#7ff70 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-LAYOUT       
NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
  creator: Column ← Column ← FractionallySizedBox ← RepaintBoundary 
  ← IndexedSemantics ←
    NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ←       
    AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree ←
    SliverList ← MediaQuery ← SliverPadding ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use 
  size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=314.2, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)      
  size: MISSING
  direction: vertical
  mainAxisAlignment: start
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  verticalDirection: down
This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth5):
    child 1: RenderConstrainedBox#d0d25 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT    
    NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
      child: RenderLimitedBox#45966 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT        
      NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        child: RenderConstrainedBox#fa9ce NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT  
    child 2: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#a3bc2 NEEDS-LAYOUT
    NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
      child: RenderConstrainedBox#57bca NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT    
      NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        child: RenderCustomPaint#92487 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT     
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderFlex#7ff70 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderFlex#60417 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#f5dd4 relayoutBoundary=up5       
NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderRepaintBoundary#ec457 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT        
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown:
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart':      
Failed assertion: line 544 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.    

Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null    
value

Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null    
value

Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null    
value
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for
x86 is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:57917/zOC4HZuw9FM=/      
I/flutter (13021): {access-control-allow-credentials: true, connection: keep-alive, x-cache-key: /data/2.5/onecall?exclude=minutely,hourly&lat=44.56&lon=-123.32&units=imperial, date: Tue, 08 Feb 2022 05:38:40 GMT, access-control-allow-origin: *, access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, content-length: 4734, content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8, server: openresty}

Another exception was thrown: RenderFlex children have non-zero flexbut incoming width constraints are unbounded.

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderFlex#50be3 relayoutBoundary=up21 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderDecoratedBox#d59df relayoutBoundary=up20 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderPositionedBox#a36e5 relayoutBoundary=up19 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderPadding#0e4cc relayoutBoundary=up18 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderPointerListener#c57e4 relayoutBoundary=up17 NEEDS-PAINT       
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderSemanticsAnnotations#3b2b0 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT  
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderMouseRegion#e8883 relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderSemanticsAnnotations#3a4ae relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT  
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
_RenderInkFeatures#fe5e0 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderCustomPaint#bffd3 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderPhysicalShape#13804 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderConstrainedBox#a37f2 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT        
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
_RenderInputPadding#15d4c relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderSemanticsAnnotations#8401d relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT   
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderFlex#a6855 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderFlex#60417 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#f5dd4 relayoutBoundary=up5       
NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderRepaintBoundary#ec457 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT        

Another exception was thrown:
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart':      
Failed assertion: line 544 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
```

Comment: Is that all the error? I can't find the error message anywhere.

Comment: @dante Modified the post to include the full terminal output instead of the snippets. Felt the snippets were more useful, but it's now modified to show the full output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The DailyWeatherForecast had to have a set width. I just wrapped the TextButton in a SizedBox with a set width and it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: DailyWeatherForecast consume as much width as posible. You can wrap DailyWeatherForecast in Expanded, it will give it remain width of row.

Comment: That wouldn't of fixed the issue, actually that kind of logic is why there was an issue in the first place. The expansion contradicted the shrinking, and by setting a static width the issue was resolved. I could always be mistaken, though.